# Anyone can see my mistake? Switch statement

Tags: javascript

**Anyone seeing the error in my code?
I don't get any return...**

Write a function getDrinkByProfession/get_drink_by_profession() that receives as input parameter a string, and produces outputs according to the following table:

Input   Output
"Jabroni"   "Patron Tequila"
"School Counselor"  "Anything with Alcohol"
"Programmer"     "Hipster Craft Beer"
"Bike Gang Member"  "Moonshine" 
"Politician"    "Your tax dollars" 
"Rapper"    "Cristal" 
*anything else* "Beer" 
Note: anything else is the default case: if the input to the function is not any of the values in the table, then the return value should be "Beer."

```
function getDrinkByProfession(param){
    switch(param){
        case "Jabroni":
        text = "Patron Tequila";
        break;
        case "School Counselor":
        text = "Anything with Alcohol";
        break;
        case "Programmer":
        text = "Hipster Craft Beer";
        break;
        case "Bike Gang Member":
        text = "Moonshine";
        break;
        case "Politician":
        text = "Your tax dollars";
        break;
        case "Rapper":
        text = "Cristal";
        break;
        default:
        text = "Beer";
      }
    }

    getDrinkByProfession("Jabroni")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow: Please check out: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Do you use `text`?

Comment: In loose mode (the default outside of modules), your code will create a global variable called `text` with the value `"Patron Tequila"`. Your code never shows the value of that variable anywhere, and doesn't return the value from the function, so you don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch is actually working just fine, its the lack of doing anything with `text` that is the problem.

For example, you can `return` it then `console.log` it.

```js
function getDrinkByProfession(param){
    var text;
    switch(param){
        case "Jabroni":
        text = "Patron Tequila";
        break;
        case "School Counselor":
        text = "Anything with Alcohol";
        break;
        case "Programmer":
        text = "Hipster Craft Beer";
        break;
        case "Bike Gang Member":
        text = "Moonshine";
        break;
        case "Politician":
        text = "Your tax dollars";
        break;
        case "Rapper":
        text = "Cristal";
        break;
        default:
        text = "Beer";
      }
      
      return text;
    }

    console.log(getDrinkByProfession("Jabroni"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `var text;` before the switch statement, and `return text;` before the function's ending brace.

Comment: Maybe, it's not clear from the question whether the OP is supposed to display the text, set a variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure what's wrong with the loop?**

```
function getDrinkByProfession(param){
  var text
  var res = param.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    endresult.push(res[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + res.substring(1))
  }
  console.log(endresult)
  switch(endresult){
    case "Jabroni":
    text = "Patron Tequila";
    break;
    case "School Counselor":
    text = "Anything with Alcohol";
    break;
    case "Programmer":
    text = "Hipster Craft Beer";
    break;
    case "Bike Gang Member":
    text = "Moonshine";
    break;
    case "Politician":
    text = "Your tax dollars";
    break;
    case "Rapper":
    text = "Cristal";
    break;
    default:
    text = "Beer";
  }
  return text
}

getDrinkByProfession("Bike Gang Member")
```